# What is the major difference between perl 5.16 to 5.24?

Tags: perl, upgrade

How will I find the difference between Perl 5.16 and 5.24?

I am able to get the difference between only the previous version, i.e. 5.22. I don't want to get only the difference between the previous version

The Perl documentation only provides the difference to the previous version.

Comment: [Differences between the 5.22.0 release and the 5.24.0 release](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta.html), If you already know the difference between perl 5.16 and 5.22 release.

Comment: is there any ways to find the things that are deprecated instead of reading the docs??.

Comment: [Perl delta perl-5.24.0](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.24.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Deprecations), You could search for Deprecations heading in each version and look for the deprecated function above Perl 5.16 release.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to check `perldelta` for every release,

https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod
https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.20.0/pod/perldelta.pod
https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/pod/perldelta.pod
https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.24.0/pod/perldelta.pod

Comment: I want to know what are the function that are deprecated in the perl 5.24 compared with perl 5.16. any idea on this??

Comment: All of those documents contain a section entitled "Deprecations", so it's easy enough to find the things that might affect you. Alternatively, install the new version of Perl on your test environment and run your test suite - you'll soon see what breaks.

Comment: does perl have any test suite itself or do you mean to run my own test suite??

Comment: What *is* "perldelta"? An executable? A document? A set of text files? A Perl module?

Comment: OK, `perldoc perldelta` displays it. ('perldoc' is not installed by default on Ubuntu - sudo `apt-get update && sudo apt-get install perl-doc`)